# React+Bootstrap complaining about childs not having unique keys, but they all do

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have used uuid to give all my components unique keys, since I am generating 90% of them with map (most of my UI is automatically generated). However, React keeps complaining that some childs of a list do not have an unique key. I am also using `Bootstrap` Row and Col components to order my UI.

When I inspect my components with the React Developer tools I can see that every single one of them has an unique key.

My approach to giving keys is, I give a key to the component and to the inner elements of that same component.

Here are a few screenshots of my components tree and the exact components React complains about:

http://prntscr.com/tkox62
http://prntscr.com/tkoxb6
http://prntscr.com/tkoxf9

As you can see, every single component has an unique key.

Error:
http://prntscr.com/tkoxpp

Row and Col are bootstrap components.

RowInCard component:

```
export default function RowInCard({ elements, toggleRNumpad }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Row key={uuid()} className="card-row">
        {elements &&
          elements.map((element) => {
            // elements in card row
            return (
              <>
                {element.typeOfElement === "TextField" && (
                  <TextField
                    key={uuid()}
                    text={element.text}
                  ></TextField>
                )}
                {element.typeOfElement === "Button" && (
                  <Button
                    key={uuid()}
                    ID={element.ID}
                  ></Button>
                )}
              </>
            );
          })}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
}
```

Button:

```
export default function Button({ ID }) {
  return (
    <Col
      key={uuid()}
    >
      {ID}
    </Col>
  );
}
```

TextField:

```
export default function TextField({ text }) {

  return (
    <Col
      key={uuid()}
      className="text-field card-element"
    >
      {text}
    </Col>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, only elements rendered in loops need `key` props. Your `Button` and `TextField` components do not need keys. However, the fragment inside your loop does:

```js
      // No `key` here, it's not in a loop
      <Row className="card-row">
        {elements &&
          elements.map((element, index) => {
            return (
              // In a loop here, need a `key`
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                {element.typeOfElement === "TextField" && (
                  <TextField
                    // No key here, its parent is not a loop
                    text={element.text}
                  ></TextField>
                )}
                {element.typeOfElement === "Button" && (
                  <Button
                    // No key here, its parent is not a loop
                    ID={element.ID}
                  ></Button>
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
      </Row>
```